# jQuery: Detect characters in the src= attribute

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to see other posts here in SO, but I'm just not capable of wrapping my head around the code examples. Note that I'm still learning jQuery/JavaScript, and any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Say I have these images across many different pages on the site:

Page 1: `<img alt="..." src="images/ss-project-name.png">`

Page 2: `<img alt="..." src="images/ss-another-project-name.png">`

Page 3: `<img alt="..." src="images/ss-yet-another-project-name.png">`

There are many of these images around the site, editing the markup is impossible, and I need to add a `class="screenshot"` to all them.

So I would end up with something like this:

`<img alt="..." src="images/ss-project-name.png" class="screenshot">`

Here are some scripts I've tried, they of course don't work, but it could give you an idea of what what I'm trying to accomplish:

Try #1:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('src') == "ss-"){
        $(this).addClass('screenshot');
    }
});
```

Try #2:

```
$("img:has([src^='ss-'])").addClass('screenshot');
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, this should work:

```
$("img[src*='ss-']").addClass('screenshot');
```

The reason your first try didn't work is because you're testing the `src` attribute to be exactly `ss-` not for containing that substring. The second try didn't work because `:has()` as [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) say:

> Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the
>   specified selector.

And also because `[src^='ss-']` would look for elements with `src` **starting** with `ss-`, and in your case they start with the string `images/`

Comment: Dang, I was so close! I was going to use `*` in my next try :). This worked perfect. I chose your answer because of the explanations of why what I tried didn't work, plus the info (and link) from the jQuery Docs for reference. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this selector: `$('img[src*="images/ss-"]').addClass('screenshot');`

It will find all files from images directory starting with `ss-`. Adding `images/` as part of the selector will avoid matching the files such as `<img src="media/miss-you-so-much.png" />`.

Comment: I wish I could chose two answers as THE answer. Your solution worked great. And yes, I agree that adding the `images/` folder is helpful. Gave you an upvote. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 $('img').each(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src'); 
        if (src.substr(0,2) == "ss-"){
            $(this).addClass('screenshot');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work. Thanks for your help though.